# Getting list of Google Calendar events using googleapis

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

Following [googleapis documentation](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client#generating-an-authentication-url) I've retrieved tokens including `refresh_token`:

```
{ access_token: 'ya29.Glv_LONG-STRING',
        token_type: 'Bearer',
        refresh_token: '1/7k6BLAH-BLAH-BLAH',
        expiry_date: 1532141656948 }
```

How can I get list of Google Calendar events using this **when `access_token` is not valid anymore**, but I have the `refresh_token`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already retrieved the refresh token. You want to retrieve an event list using Calendar API by the refresh token. If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? In this script, it supposes the following points.

- You have the refresh token which can use Calendar API.

  - The refresh token includes `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly` for retrieving the event list using Calendar API in the scopes.
- Calendar API has already been enabled at API console.

When you run the script, if the error occurs, please confirm above points.

#### Sample script :

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const calendar = google.calendar('v3');
var oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  "### client ID ###",
  "### client secret ###",
);
oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  refresh_token: "### refresh token ###",
  // access_token: "#####" // If you want to use access token, please use this.
});
calendar.events.list({
   auth: oauth2Client,
   calendarId: 'primary',
}, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(res.data);
    }
});
```

#### Note :

- When you use this sample script, please set client ID, client secret, refresh token and `calendarId` for your environment.
- I confirmed that this sample script works with the version 32.0.0 of googleapis.

#### Reference :

- [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/)
- [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.